# icheck multi color schema

Tags: css, icheck

I would like to use iCheck plugin(http://icheck.fronteed.com/) to show custom checkbox,and I referred to the sample on official site,but I find it cannot show the multi color schema on the single page.

Could anyone help me check this?

Is it possible to show following style?

[multi color schema style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xw0XL.png)

Any help is to thank in advance.

Comment: could you show out part of the code you did right now??
I could not guess to know what is the problem in your code.

Comment: @Anami sorry,I misunderstood the sample code,the question is solved.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            <ul class="form-group">
            <li class="checkbox"><input name="one" type="checkbox" value="one"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;one</li>
            <li class="checkbox"><input name="two" type="checkbox" value="two"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;two</li>
            <li class="checkbox"><input name="three" type="checkbox" value="three"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;three</li>
            <li class="checkbox"><input name="four" type="checkbox" value="four"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;four</li>
            </ul>

 $(document).ready(function(){
            $('input[name="one"]').iCheck({
                checkboxClass:'icheckbox_square-green',
                radioClass:'iradio_square'
            });
            $('input[name="two"]').iCheck({
                checkboxClass:'icheckbox_square-pink',
                radioClass:'iradio_square'
            });
            $('input[name="three"]').iCheck({
                checkboxClass:'icheckbox_square-orange',
                radioClass:'iradio_square'
            });
            $('input[name="four"]').iCheck({
                checkboxClass:'icheckbox_square-blue',
                radioClass:'iradio_square'
            });
        });
```